# Cannot resize APFS container using diskutil

Tags: hard-drive, mojave, disk-utility, partition

I've tried few suggestions on resizing disk and cannot manage to do this. My system:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *214.7 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         85.7 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +85.7 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume macOS                   68.7 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 46.8 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk1s4
```

Basically I need to grow-to-fit my partition Apple_APFS (and thereafter macOS) to size of my HDD (stated 214.7GB)

When I try to perform grow-to-fit:

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
Started APFS operation
Error: -69743: The new size must be different than the existing size
```

GUI app also fails resizing "Free Space".

Please advise.

P.S. If this gives any important context, this all happens on a VM running Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: You probably resized the VM disk after installing 10.14 or failed to erase-expand the main system device while installing 10.14. What's the hypervisor? VMware, VirtualBox or Parallels?

Comment: Hypervisor is VMWare.

OS version all the time was 10.14.6

VMWare volume was resized from 80G to 200G, and now I want to give this space to macOS, and I can't

Do you have any advise/guide on how to do this right?

Comment: AFAIR the default disk size in VMware (setting up a new guest) is 40 GiB. If you resize the disk in VMware (e.g. to 80 GB) before installing macOS and don't erase the device with Disk Utility, the macOS installer only sees the 40 GiB "disk". Do you remeber what you did in the past?

Comment: This was done by my IT team, but my view of the history is:

1) Created 80Gb drive; 2) Installed macOS; 3) After 3-4 month I requested resize to 200 GB 4) VMWare disk resized to 200 GB 5) Now we cannot give this to macOS from the inside - however, macOS sees disk0 as 200GB (as I logged diskutil)

Comment: 1st: Try the following (stepwise): 1. `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 120g` 2. `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 160g` 3. `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 214g` etc. 2nd: I will try to find an answer by setting up a similar VM guest - takes some time though...